# Centos 8 Getty restarting every 10 seconds

Tags: linux, logging, centos8

This is a new server setup, the messages log file is getting flooded with this every 10 seconds:

```
Mar 21 14:12:34 server systemd[1]: getty@getty.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.
Mar 21 14:12:34 server  systemd[1]: getty@getty.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 7166.
Mar 21 14:12:34 server systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on getty.
Mar 21 14:12:34 server systemd[1]: Started Getty on getty.
```

I have read it is not ok to disable Getty so what should I do?

```
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Getty on %I
Documentation=man:agetty(8) man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
Documentation=http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service getty-pre.target
After=rc-local.service

# If additional gettys are spawned during boot then we should make
# sure that this is synchronized before getty.target, even though
# getty.target didn't actually pull it in.
Before=getty.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

# IgnoreOnIsolate causes issues with sulogin, if someone isolates
# rescue.target or starts rescue.service from multi-user.target or
# graphical.target.
Conflicts=rescue.service
Before=rescue.service

# On systems without virtual consoles, don't start any getty. Note
# that serial gettys are covered by serial-getty@.service, not this
# unit.
ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty0

[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
# The '-o' option value tells agetty to replace 'login' arguments with an
# option to preserve environment (-p), followed by '--' for safety, and then
# the entered username.
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes

# Unset locale for the console getty since the console has problems
# displaying some internationalized messages.
UnsetEnvironment=LANG LANGUAGE LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT LC_IDENTIFICATION

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
DefaultInstance=tty1
```

Comment: can you add your systemd getty.service file content here?

Comment: added the service file